# How to repeat the same image a number of times in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to repeat an image-"box1" throughout the width of the page. I tried the following but it isn't working.

```js
var count = $(window).width() / $("#box1").width();

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("top-section");
  paragraph.innerHTML += "<img src='images/box1.png' id='box1'html>";
}
```

```css
#top-section {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-section"></div>
```

Comment: "it isnt working" isn't enough for us to know what is wrong. Do you have an error message?

Comment: Why don't you try a repeating background image?

Comment: Put the sample code on https://jsfiddle.net may help too :)

Comment: What is `#box1`? Is its `width` known when this code executes? If that element is an image, then that is unlikely to be the case (as you need to wait for it to load)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add multiple #box1 elements. An ID must be unique, you can't repeat them. If you're adding multiple images I'd suggest using a class instead

Comment: tried using background-image,still not working:
#top-section{

background-image: url("images/box1.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}

Comment: An empty `<div>` with `float:left` will shrink to zero width and height, so the background image won't show.

Comment: so, background-image approach isnt correct?

Comment: It depends on your context. A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help demonstrate your issue. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/73erhak0/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works fine for me.
Check it out...

Just clone element what u need and append it inside the section.

```js
var count = $(window).width() / $(".box1").last().width();

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  $("#top-section").append($(".box1").last().clone(true));
}
```

```css
#top-section {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-section">
  <img src="images/box1.png" class="box1">
</div>
```

Comment: That was pretty useful. Thanks alot.

Comment: Note that I removed your snippet as the value of `count` is `Infinity`, which when used as a loop causes the browser to hang until the operation times out. quite why this is the accepted answer I can't even guess.

Comment: While the box is exist and has a width it's gonna work) There just can be situation when you don't have the picture and it can coz the problems..
Oh.. I understood about snippet.. Im new to this site... The snippet doesn't has the picture at all.. That's why it can't calculate the count.. I will be more careful in future..